# is there any way to hide list view Item in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

is there any way to hide list view Item in ListView ?

Comment: If it is winforms, tag it as winforms instead of putting (not wpf) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the rendering logic and choose for yourself which items to be ignored (i.e. not to be rendered, but still exist in the item collection).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a specific row, you can use a filtered view as `ListView`'s data source such as `DataView`. By setting filters on it, it will hide specific rows. You can also create custom filtered views.